Getting LicenseException and often Tridion 10 microservices pods restarts in AKS
We have deployed Tridion 10 RWS micro services in AKS (Discovery, Content Service, Deployer Service) and receiving error message like shared below w.r.t License, also pods are getting restarted often automatically. can you please suggest why that happens?
Removed below content as it contains some client information.

The behaviour you see is correct. Within your setup, each container instance will see one of the vCPUs as an available processor, and hence will consume 1 license. In addition, without limits, each container may consume up to 6 VPUs per host server. This will clearly over consume licenses. The recommendation for deploying containers within such an environment is to use hard CPU resource limits for each container. You the have exact control of how many CPUs each service consumes from the license pool.
See https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/04/19/java-17-whats-new-openjdks-container-awareness#diagnostic_options_for_debugging for details of how Java 17 sees CPUs within a container. Keep in mind that partial CPU limit values (such as 512) will consume a whole CPU from the licence pool.
Thanks.
